# In relational algebra SQL how can I select the row that is not on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-algebra

So for example I have two tables, Order and QualifiedOrder

ORDER

```
Order# | Customer#
------------------
16     |   7

23     |   9 

21     |   2  

59     |   5
```

QualifiedOrder

```
QualifiedOrder# | DateApplied
----------------------------- 
23              |  9/10/16

21              | 10/2/15
```

how to list the order that are not qualified? (list only the data in the order table that are not in the QualifiedOrder table) in relational algebra

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Eg what are the rows where Order# is an order number? What are the rows where QualifiedOrder# is an order number for a qualified order? What are the rows where Order# is an order number for a qualified order? What are the rows where Order# & Customer are an order number and customer for a qualified order? PS What relational operator gives you rows from a table that are not in another table?

Comment: Why are you tagging sql or mysql? What is SQL doing in your title?

Comment: `Order antijoin QualifiedOrder`?

Comment: In relational algebra, it's referred to as a "tuple" in a "relation", not a "row" in a "table". And you are looking for an "antijoin" of the two relations.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command and please change the names `ORDER` and `Order` to any other as `ORDER` is a keyword for sql.

```
SELECT 
    Order 
FROM 
    ORDER 
WHERE 
    Order not IN (
        SELECT 
            QualifiedOrder 
        FROM 
            QualifiedOrder
    )
```

Another way using join :

```
SELECT 
   ORDER.Order
FROM 
   ORDER 
JOIN 
   QualifiedOrder
ON
   ORDER.Order <> QualifiedOrder.QualifiedOrder
```

And try to change the last query to relational algebra.

Comment: how do you write it in relational algebra?

Comment: @student001 http://www.databasteknik.se/webbkursen/relalg-lecture/ check it

Comment: Your first query is relational *calculus* SQL, no?